# SVG <path/> <animation> not working

Tags: wordpress, svg

This following svg code plays the first part of animation but rest 3 wont. Its on a wordpress website, is that has something to do with it? If i open the svg from computer in a browser it works fine. Thanks in advance

```
    <g>    
    <path d="M352,418.9c0,30.3-0.1,60.6,0.1,91c0,5.8-2.1,9.1-7.2,11c-26.7,10-53.3,20-80,29.8c-7.9,2.9-17.9-4.7-17.9-13.2
        c-0.1-40,0.2-80-0.4-119.9c-0.4-24.6-0.4-49.3-0.7-73.9c-0.1-7.3,0.7-8.3,7.7-9.9c27.1-6.2,54.2-12.4,81.3-18.6
        c10.1-2.3,17.2,3.5,17.2,13.8C352,358.9,352,388.9,352,418.9z"
        fill="url(#imgpattern)" id="core_type"/>

        <animate xlink:href="#core_type"
        attributeName="d"
        attributeType="XML"
        from="M352,418.9c0,30.3-0.1,60.6,0.1,91c0,5.8-2.1,9.1-7.2,11c-26.7,10-53.3,20-80,29.8c-7.9,2.9-17.9-4.7-17.9-13.2
                c-0.1-40,0.2-80-0.4-119.9c-0.4-24.6-0.4-49.3-0.7-73.9c-0.1-7.3,0.7-8.3,7.7-9.9c27.1-6.2,54.2-12.4,81.3-18.6
                c10.1-2.3,17.2,3.5,17.2,13.8C352,358.9,352,388.9,352,418.9z"
        to="M202,350.9c0,30.3-0.1,60.6,0.1,91c0,5.8-2.1,9.1-7.2,11c-26.7,10-53.3,20-80,29.8c-7.9,2.9-17.9-4.7-17.9-13.2
            c-0.1-40,0.2-80-0.4-119.9c-0.4-24.6-0.4-49.3-0.7-73.9c-0.1-7.3,0.7-8.3,7.7-9.9c27.1-6.2,54.2-12.4,81.3-18.6
            c10.1-2.3,17.2,3.5,17.2,13.8C352,358.9,352,388.9,352,418.9z"
        dur="2s"

        begin="0s; animation4.end"

        fill="freeze" id="animation" />


        <animate xlink:href="#core_type"
        attributeName="d"
        attributeType="XML"
        from="M202,350.9c0,30.3-0.1,60.6,0.1,91c0,5.8-2.1,9.1-7.2,11c-26.7,10-53.3,20-80,29.8c-7.9,2.9-17.9-4.7-17.9-13.2
            c-0.1-40,0.2-80-0.4-119.9c-0.4-24.6-0.4-49.3-0.7-73.9c-0.1-7.3,0.7-8.3,7.7-9.9c27.1-6.2,54.2-12.4,81.3-18.6
            c10.1-2.3,17.2,3.5,17.2,13.8C352,358.9,352,388.9,352,418.9z"
        to="M202,350.9c0,30.3-0.1,60.6,0.1,91c0,5.8-2.1,9.1-7.2,11c-26.7,10-53.3,20-80,29.8c-7.9,2.9-17.9-4.7-17.9-13.2
            c-0.1-40,0.2-80-0.4-119.9c-0.4-24.6-0.4-49.3-0.7-73.9c-0.1-7.3,0.7-8.3,7.7-9.9c27.1-6.2,54.2-12.4,81.3-18.6
            c10.1-2.3,17.2,3.5,17.2,13.8C352,358.9,352,388.9,352,418.9z"
        dur="2s"

        begin="animation.end"

        fill="freeze" id="animation2" />



        <animate xlink:href="#core_type"
        attributeName="d"
        attributeType="XML"
        to="M352,418.9c0,30.3-0.1,60.6,0.1,91c0,5.8-2.1,9.1-7.2,11c-26.7,10-53.3,20-80,29.8c-7.9,2.9-17.9-4.7-17.9-13.2
                c-0.1-40,0.2-80-0.4-119.9c-0.4-24.6-0.4-49.3-0.7-73.9c-0.1-7.3,0.7-8.3,7.7-9.9c27.1-6.2,54.2-12.4,81.3-18.6
                c10.1-2.3,17.2,3.5,17.2,13.8C352,358.9,352,388.9,352,418.9z"
        from="M202,350.9c0,30.3-0.1,60.6,0.1,91c0,5.8-2.1,9.1-7.2,11c-26.7,10-53.3,20-80,29.8c-7.9,2.9-17.9-4.7-17.9-13.2
            c-0.1-40,0.2-80-0.4-119.9c-0.4-24.6-0.4-49.3-0.7-73.9c-0.1-7.3,0.7-8.3,7.7-9.9c27.1-6.2,54.2-12.4,81.3-18.6
            c10.1-2.3,17.2,3.5,17.2,13.8C352,358.9,352,388.9,352,418.9z"
        dur="2s"

        begin="animation2.end"

        fill="freeze" id="animation3" />

        <animate xlink:href="#core_type"
        attributeName="d"
        attributeType="XML"
        from="M352,418.9c0,30.3-0.1,60.6,0.1,91c0,5.8-2.1,9.1-7.2,11c-26.7,10-53.3,20-80,29.8c-7.9,2.9-17.9-4.7-17.9-13.2
                c-0.1-40,0.2-80-0.4-119.9c-0.4-24.6-0.4-49.3-0.7-73.9c-0.1-7.3,0.7-8.3,7.7-9.9c27.1-6.2,54.2-12.4,81.3-18.6
                c10.1-2.3,17.2,3.5,17.2,13.8C352,358.9,352,388.9,352,418.9z"
        to="M352,418.9c0,30.3-0.1,60.6,0.1,91c0,5.8-2.1,9.1-7.2,11c-26.7,10-53.3,20-80,29.8c-7.9,2.9-17.9-4.7-17.9-13.2
                c-0.1-40,0.2-80-0.4-119.9c-0.4-24.6-0.4-49.3-0.7-73.9c-0.1-7.3,0.7-8.3,7.7-9.9c27.1-6.2,54.2-12.4,81.3-18.6
                c10.1-2.3,17.2,3.5,17.2,13.8C352,358.9,352,388.9,352,418.9z"
        dur="2s"

        begin="animation3.end"

        fill="freeze" id="animation4" />
</g>
```

Comment: Some of your animation elements seem to be missing from and to attributes.

Comment: Yes i left them so there can be a pause.

Comment: How come its working from my computer then.

Comment: And it does finishes the first part of animation from server.

Comment: I Updated the code filled in missing to=, from=.